# Is it possible to have a finite number of quantum numbers?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

As far as I know, quantum numbers range upto infinity, let it be a rigid rotator, the hydrogen atom, etc. I am thinking if there can be a system for which the quantum numbers of the wavefunctions, and hence the wavefunctions themselves, are finite. Mathematically, I am thinking about wavefunctions:
$$
\Psi_{n_1, n_2,n_3,…,n_m}
$$
Where,
$$
n_1=1,2,3,…,N_1$$
$$
n_2=1,2,3,…,N_2$$
$$
……….………$$
$$
n_m=1,2,3,…,N_m$$

## Edit

Considering the answer given to my I should like to extend my question: is there any finite dimensional alternative to the Hilbert space? This surely sounds like a joke but its rather more practical to have a finite world than an ideally infinite space.

Comment: "quantum numbers range from $1$ to $∞$" - you mean apart from (say) spin in the hydrogen atom?

Comment: Of course yes, I am just talking about the principal quantum numbers. I hope wavefunctions without ANY quantum number ranging upto infinity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Morse potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_potential) 
$$
V(r)=D_e(e^{-2a(r-r_c)}-2e^{-a(r-r_c)})
$$
is important as historically it is the first example of a continuous potential that supports finitely many bound states, i.e. there is an upper value of principal quantum number.

The energies are given by 
$$
\epsilon_n= -(\lambda-n-\textstyle\frac{1}{2})^2
$$
with $n=0,1,\ldots [\lambda-\frac{1}{2}]$ and $\lambda$ is the combination
$$
\lambda=\frac{\sqrt{2mD_e}}{a\hbar}\, .
$$
Basically the number of bound states is related to the depth $D_e$ of the potential and the length scale $a$ of this potential.

Before this example, only a finite well (which is discontinuous) was known to support finitely many bound states.

Comment: I like this example, but doesn't *any* finite potential well support a finite number of (or zero) bound states?

Comment: @march I would not bet on this being *always* true.  Imagine for instance a Coulomb-like potential where the core is replaced by a uniformly charged sphere so the potential is linear in $r$ for some small $r/a$, but $1/r$ outside.  Then by perturbation theory you'd still have infinitely many bound states but a technically finite potential at $r=0$.

Comment: That's interesting! If that turns out to be true, that's a serious violation of my intuition (which is fine, but still...). I mean: my reasoning would go something like this, thinking semi-classically. As the energy of the bound state increases, the number of nodes it has also increases, and hence the amount of *kinetic* energy it has increases. Eventually, the KE due to those extra nodes is larger than the difference between the bottom and top of the well, at which point the state is no longer bound.

Comment: The Dirac delta well has a single bound state. Does that qualify?

Comment: However, maybe I'm using the finite square well in my thinking too much. There, you have to cram the nodes inside the well, and so the KE shoots up. For a potential that is less than 0 *everywhere*, perhaps the nodes just get pushed out farther and farther, making it so that the KE doesn't increase without bound (this seems to be what happens with hydrogenic wave functions, so...).

Comment: @BillN not really continuous...

Comment: @march I should be honest here and remark that - (and you want to check this yourself) - the solutions to the Morse potential actually slightly violate the boundary conditions of the problem as they technically extend slightly in the $r<0$ region.  This bug is ignored on physical grounds.

Comment: @march in the "artificial" example I give of the "Coulomb+sphere" potential the potential is continuous but it's derivative is not at the boundary between the sphere and the vacuum, i.e. the potential is piecewise function.  I do not know what this implies in terms of the number of nodes.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero. I'm assuming that that's a symptom of modeling an interatomic interaction with a potential that isn't infinitely repulsive at $r=0$. As long as the wave function is "zero-enough" at $r=0$, I would imagine it's good enough for modeling purposes. As for your other comment: I don't think that discontinuities in the potential are going to change things either way.  I think what matters is if it's possible to increase the number of nodes of a wave function without bound without increasing the kinetic energy without bound, and I don't think discontinuities will affect that. Anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If we interpret "wavefunction" in the usual sense, as the space of states of a particle moving in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then this is not possible. This is simply because the Hilbert space is $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the space of square integrable functions, which is infinite dimensional; and every basis must have the same number of elements. You can have finite dimensional Hilbert spaces, of which spin is the most common example, but they're not really the wavefunctions of a particle moving in space.

Comment: Or they can be - by using a suitable hamiltonian which restricts the dynamics to only a finite-dimensional subspace of an otherwise infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty do you know of an example? I don't see how one can get around the fact that the Hilbert space is always $L^2$, a fact that is independent of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: The full Hilbert space is always $L^2$, but the dynamics need not explore the full Hilbert space. A suitable example is a set of ions in an ion trap, addressed by lasers that are sharply resonant with only a few atomic and translational transitions: if the state starts off within that set of states, the dynamics will keep it there, and you can effectively forget about the rest of the Hilbert space. This is a foundational aspect to all of quantum information processing, be it on ions, cold atoms, superconducting circuits, photons, you name it.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty. Or, really, any time there's some conserved quantity like angular momentum that would restrict the dynamics to a finite-dimensional subspace.